# Nesting if statements

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to nest the following IF statements. In order to have a different word returned  according to what word is in the other cell.

`=(IF((D2 = "Your Spouse / Partner"), "my partner", “x”)), (IF((D2 = "Your Friend"), "my friend”, "x"))`

It's not working but individually the formulas do work.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the extra parenthesis and putting the second IF as the third argument of the first:

`=IF(D2 = "Your Spouse / Partner", "my partner", IF(D2 = "Your Friend", "my friend”, "x"))`